# How to know how a div got display:none (hidden) added? DOM breakpoint not firing

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

I have a div which is hidden when the page is displayed and I am trying to find out what script is hiding it. I see that it has style="display:none". The page comes from the web server without this style. I have used Chrome Dev Tools and added a DOM breakpoint on attribute change in the Sources panel and a similar one in the Elements panel on the div. The Sources panel doesn't show the "display:none". When I refresh the page, none of the breakpoints fire. However when I hide/display the div manually in the console using jQuery, a breakpoint inside jQuery code fires. This tells me the breakpoint is set up correctly. I tried manually to find in the script and couldn't locate where the hiding is done. There are many ways to reference the div.

**Any ideas how the div could have been hidden?**

Comment: Try inspecting your scripts that are being loaded onto the page and look for the code which may hide a dom node.  Search for these key terms (try both single and double quotes where applicable): `.display`, `["display"]`, `"none"`, `.hide(`

Comment: I did but this is a large app with many external js files. I mentioned the fact that I did a manual search. The div doesn't have an id so I searched for all references to its class. There are a ton of ways to reference an element. From one of the parents, or children so it's a crapshot now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Javascript manually. It was inside a function defined in a namespace. The classname was assigned to an object property and the thing was called like $(objectname.propertyname).hide(). For some reason it seems the DOM breakpoint bypasses it. I would like to know still how to make the breakpoint fire for those.